# In an Android AAR library can I expose a public API and hide the implementation?

Tags: android, aar

This seems like such a basic question but I cannot find the information anywhere.

I would like to build an AAR that exposes a public API but hides the implementation so that the implementation will not be called directly.

I don't see a way to do this other than obfuscating the packages I want to encapsulate (hide).

Comment: The rules for Java are the same whether that Java is in source form, is in a plain JAR, or is in a JAR wrapped in an AAR. It is all based on Java access rules (e.g., anything that is `public` can be accessed by clients of the library). You will not find instructions specific for an AAR, because the fact that it is an AAR is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is to expose my API through a factory that always returns interfaces.   Each interface contains only the methods I want to expose.

Of course, there are public methods in the implementations that the caller could still access directly, but at least it becomes clear which methods are intended to be in the public interface.